# Github API - find out who closed a pull request

Tags: github-api, pull-request

How do I find out who closed a pull request using the Github API?

e.g. [this pull request](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/pull/4461) was opened by myakura, closed by markdotto. But https://api.github.com/repos/twitter/bootstrap/pulls/4461 doesn't show any reference to markdotto.

Comment: As far as GitHub is concerned, the PR was **closed** and not **merged**.  So of course nothing will show up under `merged_by` and related fields.  However, if you fetch the PR **as an issue** (https://api.github.com/repositories/2126244/issues/4461), you will see a `closed_by` field which contains the information you're looking for.